# Remove last certain number of elements from a list

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

I have a `ArrayList` of values that I add on to based on certain conditions. I have a `Button` called `back` whose function is to clear the last added elements from the `ArrayList`. I keep track of how many elements were added by use of a `counter` variable.

So I have this skeleton function where `itemList` is the list that I want to remove the elements from and `howManyElementsToRemove` is the number (`counter`) of elements I want to remove from the parsed list. I have looked at the function options I get when using `itemList.remove()`, but I don't know which one will be the best option.

```
  private fun removeElements(itemList: ArrayList<Int>, howManyElementsToRemove: Int){

        //I am not sure how to approach this
    }
```

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple for loop (*or repeat*) should be enough:

```kotlin
private fun removeElements(list: ArrayList<Int>, numberOfRemovals: Int){
    for(count in 0 until numberOfRemovals){
        list.removeLast() //Or as Ben Shmuel mentioned, removeLastOrNull()
    }
}
```

We can test this using an input:

```kotlin
val primes = arrayListOf(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 23)
val numberOfRemovals = 3
removeElements(primes, numberOfRemovals)
println(primes)
```

Result:
`[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]`

Answer (score 3):

Another more intuitive approach is to use `dropLast(n: Int)`.

```
var list = listOf(5, 10, 15, 20)
var result = list.dropLast(2)
println(result) //[5, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the last added you can use `removeLast()` or `removeLastOrNull()`

For example:

```
val itemList = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
val howManyElementsToRemove = 3
 
 repeat(howManyElementsToRemove){itemList.removeLastOrNull()}
 
 print(itemList)
//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

if you use `removeLast()` with `howManyElementsToRemove` when it size is greater than `itemList` size  you might get  `NoSuchElementException("List is empty.")`

Answer (score 0):

If you track the size of List each time, then best option is:

```
itemList.subList(prevSize, curSize).clear()
```

where  curSize  = current size of List and prevSize = previous Size